# Android - Andengine - How to use native UI SKD

Tags: android, user-interface, sdk, native, andengine

I want use the native sdk interface layout, (How a normal app) to design my game menu, and link it to the BaseGameActivity, or GameScene, I know how to design the interface using sdk native, but I dont know how implement it on andengine :S

I cant find any solution, I will hope anybody can help me to find the best method, or the way to use these.

Sorry for my bad english.

---

More info: I know how to add a little framelayout on my baseactivity, but I can a set of menus (2/3) and that you can move on it, and enter on the game and exit of the game :)

Sorry my english again

Answer (score 3):

Well, I do this works :)

Only create a normal activity, with the layout etc.. and use the intent.putExtra(); to send a particular info to the BaseGameActivy, Then, on onCreateResources() I set a serie of conditions to determine that I press before, and set the wished scene.

Sorry my english :)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: imported tutorials from original website

## How to use UI Android SDK with AndEndine

NOTE : You may have filling errors if you change width and heights in these layouts so be carefull (this solution works with fullscreen usage)

### XML layout

In your project's directory *res/layout* create an empty file named *themainactivity.xml* and put the following content inside.

Notes : Set the attribute `tools:context` to your application activity name, beginning with a dot (here: .MyMainActivity)

**XML layout file: res/layout/themainactivity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- code placed here will be above the AndEngine render -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Java class

You just have to specify the IDs in your class.

**MyMainActivity.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleLayoutGameActivity;

public class MyMainActivity extends SimpleLayoutGameActivity  
{
    @Override
    protected int getLayoutID()
    {
        return R.layout.themainactivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID()
    {
        return R.id.gameSurfaceView;
    }
}
```

---

## Create a custom Android SDK layout in AndEngine

### XML layout

WARNING: the root node must be a merge node ! Inside this you can do what you want.

**XML layout file: res/layout/my_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:text="Dat button" />
  </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

[image: A quick view of the result]

### The controller class

For being able to use your interface you have to link it to the XML view using the inflater service.

NOTE: The UI Java code is compiled when you switch to the WYSIWIG editor so if you don't add the linking code below you won't see the contents of the layout in the activities that use it.

**Custom layout: MyView.java**

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyView extends LinearLayout 
{
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        // Link to the XML view
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_view, this, true);

        // Link to the XML view (alternative using service, you can delete if you don't need it)
        //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, this);
    }
}
```

### Reuse in an other activity

Just add this code in the activity layout.

```
<com.example.MyView
    android:id="@+id/myView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```